# Incorrect dimensions sciKit learn Lasso

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to find the solution to Ax = b where A has the dimension 3x1, x has dimension 1x2 and b has dimension 3x2. I also want x to be sparse.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
clf = Lasso(alpha=.01)
A  = np.array([[0], [1], [2]])
b = np.array([[0,1],[1,4],[6,2]])
clf.fit(A,b)
```

However I get the error [image]

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't post text as picture

Answer (score 0):

Those dimensions make not much sense to me.

**Matrix-multiplication A*x=b is defined for** `A: n,m and x: m,p` with the result `b: n, p`.

In your case it's either a row-vec / col-vec multiplication (**inner-product**).
But: (1,3) * (3,1) = (1,1). In this case b (3,2) cannot used for subtraction.

Or a col-vec / row-vec multiplication (**outer-product**).
But: (3,1) * (1,3) = (3,3). Again b (3,2) is not compatible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What's wrong with n=3, m = 1 and p = 2? Don't the dimensions work out?

Comment: For solving Ax=0 yes, but not for solving Ax=b, because the dimension of b is not right. (Great downvoting without pointing to issues btw.)